# How Can I Make Sure That I Write Consistently With A Busy School Schedule?

Tags: process, discipline

As a writer, one of my biggest weaknesses is that I find it very hard to write consistently. I know that many successful writers had a daily writing count that they kept to for long periods of time. However, I find this very hard to schedule around my normal life. It isn't so much a matter of fighting writers-block, as I can really force myself to write whatever I am feeling, but more a manner of finding the energy and time to write consistently every day regardless of my personal schedule. I find it hard to write consistently without compromising my family, work, or school.

How can I balance everything while still making sure to write daily?

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches:

1. Relinquish something else to make time for writing.

   You cannot expect to fit everything that you'd like to do into a day. There's just too many things that one might want to do. Work, household, family, friends, hobbies *and writing* are simply more than can be done in 24 hours. You can either get up earlier and sleep less like Elisabeth George does (who forces herself to get up, like many writers do, at 4:50 a.m.) or forego one (or part of) the other things that you do each day. For example, you might work one hour less each day, and earn less, and use that hour for writing.
2. Write in each little time slot that presents itself.

   One writer, whose name I forget, reportedly wrote her first SF novel in the breaks as a school teacher. Ally Condie [wrote for every fifteen minutes that she had](https://www.instagram.com/p/C3GNfcYvlMW/) while being a single parent of four kids, one with special needs, during COVID lockdown. It's all a question of willpower and how important writing is to you. If you want it, just do it. No excuses.
3. (Yeah, I know. I said two approaches. But.)

   You say you have to balance family, work, and school. Potentially, all of them are full time jobs on their own. And even if you aren't a single parent, don't work full time, and don't go to a full time school like high school, adding a fourth job to the three you already have might simply be impossible – if not because of time, then emotionally and mentally. You might need to wait until one or more of those three other jobs are done: Once you have finished school or the kids are out of the house, you'll suddenly have more time on your hands. And maybe then you can easier write besides your day job. Sometimes we have to get through one phase of life first before we can begin the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Make a schedule.

Put down what time you are spending on what.  This allows you to find gaps where you can write.  It can also let you identify time that is not, in fact, spent on something useful and dedicate it to writing instead.